# Конвертировать в кодировку UTF8

Tags: c++, кодировка, utf-8

Есть замечательный способ создать строку уже в кодировке `utf8`:

```
string str = u8"ежик"
```

А можно так же без лишних бубнотанцев сделать с уже готовой строкой, если я получаю её как аргумент функции?

```
foo("ежик");
void foo(string str) {
   ...
}
```

Мне просто нужно получить строку в кодировке `utf8` в `string` либо `const char*`. Можно это сделать не городя огромную стену кода?

Comment: А вы знаете в какой кодировки к вам приходит строка в функцию?

Comment: @Unick я отправляю строку точно так же через foo("ежик"); я не знаю, какая это кодировка, так что назову её "стандартная". И сразу скажу - нет, я не могу просто так взять и написать u8 перед строкой.

Comment: Кодировка, в которой будет сохранено содержимое строкового литерала, определяется компилятором. Если у вас какой-нибудь gcc, то наверняка он по-умолчанию сохранит в ней.

Comment: @VTT использую MSVS 2017

Comment: @Vermww, а ваша задача имено так и выглядит как вы описали или вы её упостили для вопроса? Может вам использовать wstring, там хотя бы однозначно из какой кодировки переводить в utf8

Comment: @Unick да, именно так и выглядит, однако, мне нужно будет потом преобразовать строку в const char*. Я пробовал использовать wstring, но как его преобразовать именно в const char*, а не в const wchar*, я не понял.

Comment: Студию можно заставить сохранить литерал в utf8 сохранив исходник в кодировке utf8 без BOM.

Comment: @Vermww, >>И сразу скажу - нет, я не могу просто так взять и написать u8 перед строкой.<< почему? кто-то запрещает? или msvc это почему-то не умеет?

Comment: @Fat-Zer это только сейчас я вручную пишу строки, в будущем я так же буду пользоваться уже готовой строкой, которую возьму ещё от куда-нибудь, и мне в любом случае нужно сейчас понять, как перевести строку в utf8, а не строить костыли в будущем.

Comment: @Vermww там есть функция watring-> string utf8 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4358870/convert-wstring-to-string-encoded-in-utf-8

Comment: @Vermww, это другой вопрос, универсального способа на уровне стандарта нет: всё зависит от того, откуда ты будешь получать строки и в какой кодировке... Если все строки в текущей (или хотя бы существующей в системе) локали, то можно сообразить что-то через wstringstream/codecvt, но там будет много подводных камней...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Не знаю насколько полезно это вам будет, но...
В моём проекте под Windows присутствуют операции с кодировками cp1251 и utf8, которые покрываются такими функциями:

1251 в utf8:

```
string cp1251_to_utf8(const char *str){
    string res; 
    int result_u, result_c;
    result_u = MultiByteToWideChar(1251, 0, str, -1, 0, 0);
    if(!result_u ){return 0;}
    wchar_t *ures = new wchar_t[result_u];
    if(!MultiByteToWideChar(1251, 0, str, -1, ures, result_u)){
        delete[] ures;
        return 0;
    }
    result_c = WideCharToMultiByte(65001, 0, ures, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    if(!result_c){
        delete [] ures;
        return 0;
    }
    char *cres = new char[result_c];
    if(!WideCharToMultiByte(65001, 0, ures, -1, cres, result_c, 0, 0)){
        delete[] cres;
        return 0;
    }
    delete[] ures;
    res.append(cres);
    delete[] cres;
    return res;
}
```

Проверка на UTF8:

```
bool is_valid_utf8(const char * string){
    if(!string){return true;}
    const unsigned char * bytes = (const unsigned char *)string;
    unsigned int cp;
    int num;
    while(*bytes != 0x00){
        if((*bytes & 0x80) == 0x00){
            // U+0000 to U+007F 
            cp = (*bytes & 0x7F);
            num = 1;
        }
        else if((*bytes & 0xE0) == 0xC0){
            // U+0080 to U+07FF 
            cp = (*bytes & 0x1F);
            num = 2;
        }
        else if((*bytes & 0xF0) == 0xE0){
            // U+0800 to U+FFFF 
            cp = (*bytes & 0x0F);
            num = 3;
        }
        else if((*bytes & 0xF8) == 0xF0){
            // U+10000 to U+10FFFF 
            cp = (*bytes & 0x07);
            num = 4;
        }
        else{return false;}
        bytes += 1;
        for(int i = 1; i < num; ++i){
            if((*bytes & 0xC0) != 0x80){return false;}
            cp = (cp << 6) | (*bytes & 0x3F);
            bytes += 1;
        }
        if( (cp > 0x10FFFF) ||
            ((cp <= 0x007F) && (num != 1)) || 
            ((cp >= 0xD800) && (cp <= 0xDFFF)) ||
            ((cp >= 0x0080) && (cp <= 0x07FF)  && (num != 2)) ||
            ((cp >= 0x0800) && (cp <= 0xFFFF)  && (num != 3)) ||
            ((cp >= 0x10000)&& (cp <= 0x1FFFFF)&& (num != 4)) ){return false;}
    }
    return true;
}
```

string в wstring:

```
wstring string_to_wstring(string str){
    wstring convertedString;
    int requiredSize = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, str.c_str(), -1, 0, 0);
    if( requiredSize > 0){
        vector<wchar_t> buffer(requiredSize);
        MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, str.c_str(), -1, &buffer[0], requiredSize);
        convertedString.assign(buffer.begin(), buffer.end() - 1);
    }
    return convertedString;
}
```

Comment: Да! Именно то, что мне нужно! Спасибо!

Comment: @Vermww, пожалуйста!