# Есть ли минусы использования wchar_t и wstring?

Tags: c++

Пробую написать клиент-серверное приложение с сервером на C++ а клиентом на Python. Передаю на сервер, например, сообщения с русскими символами, которые идут в кодировке UTF-8. На приеме `recv(...)` закономерно возникает проблема, что в буфер я кладу мусор.

Я нашел способ нейтрализовать эту проблему, используя `wchar_t` и `MultiByteToWideChar(...)`. Но после продолжительных копаний в интернете нашёл комментарий достаточно опытного человека, а именно: `Тип std::wstring хранит символы типа wchar_t, который, в зависимости от настроек компилятора, может занимать 2 или 4 байта. Это делает тип std::wstring столь же неоднозначным, как и WCHAR. Поэтому и были созданы типы со строгим размером символа: std::u16string и std::u32string. Сейчас рекомендуется пользоваться ими вместе с std::string.`

Собственно вопрос: как на сегодняшний день ГРАМОТНО совершать подобного рода действия?
P.S. Мне не нужен вариант, который будет "легче", хочется научиться делать правильно! Спасибо

Отправляю с клиента(python):

```
text = 'Привет мир'
sock.send(text.encode('utf-8'))
```

получаю:

```
char text[256];
wchar_t text_w[256];
recv(newConnection,text, sizeof(text), NULL);
MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, text, -1, text_w, sizeof(text_w));
```

Если не преобразовать в char_t, то как выразились ниже, в переменной text лежит Utf-8. Но если я захочу распарсить полученное сообщение, получится ли у меня это?
Например, буду искать посылки, где будет встречаться определенное слово?

Comment: Если сервер не обрабатывает строки посимвольно, то используйте UTF-8. Если обрабатывает, то возможны варинты. Среди которых я бы всё равно работал с UTF-8.

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос какие операции вы производите над текстом.

Comment: Не столько от настроек компилятора, сколько от платформы (вроде на винде 2, а на остальных 4). *"На приеме recv(...) закономерно возникает проблема, что в буфер я кладу мусор"* Не мусор, а UTF-8. Может его и использовать?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat дополнил. Мне не совсем понятно, что значит работать дальше с Utf-8. Если я захочу сравнить полученную строку ? Вывести ее на печать? Передать куда-то. Разве я могу это сделать, если в переменной text  не то, что мне нужно?

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy дополнил

Comment: Стандартный подход - передача и долговременное хранение в кодировке UTF-8, а (полноценная) обработка в UTF-16.

Comment: *"Если я захочу сравнить полученную строку?"* Без проблем, сравнивайте с другой строкой в той же кодировке. *"Вывести ее на печать?"* Вроде можно как-то настроить виндовую консоль на вывод utf-8. На линуксах это работает из коробки. В крайнем случае, можно конвертировать перед печатью. *"искать посылки, где будет встречаться определенное слово"* Переводите слово в utf-8 и ищите, в чем проблема?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat да нет проблемы, я ведь не знаю как это можно провернуть, поэтому и задаю здесь вопросы. Что значит перевести слово в utf-8? Вот , допустим, я получил этот буфер в utf-8. И у меня есть `std::string str = "Привет"` или `char*`. Как мне это сделать? например, как [тут в принятом ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/783946/Конвертировать-в-кодировку-utf8)?

Comment: По идее, просто убедиться, что исходный код сохранен в utf-8, и тогда будет работать без перевода. Если пользуетесь visual studio, то возможно нужно поставить какой-то флажок, чтобы он не ругался на utf-8 в коде, не уверен.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat в общем получилось добиться того, о чем Вы говорите командой `#pragma execution_character_set("utf-8")`. После этого строки действительно стали одинаковы

Comment: [Вот тут](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/execution-charset-set-execution-character-set?view=msvc-160) пишут, что этого же самого можно добиться флагом компилятора `/utf-8`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat , спасибо. Еще можно префикс `u8` при инициализации добавить